# Is it possible to check if source/target are the same for a drag&drop operation (in java)?

Tags: java, matlab, drag-and-drop

**Context**

I want to create a listbox component for Matlab in which I can reorder items and drop files from some explorer window only using mouse-gestures.

Such component does not seems to exist so I need to create my own. I found two interesting pointers to start from on [FileExchange](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/):

- [Reorderable Listbox](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37642-reorderable-listbox) : To support for reordering by dragging items.
- [dndcontrol](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53511-drag---drop-functionality-for-java-gui-components): To support for dragging files from some explorer window.

I'm thus trying to merge both to create the custom listbox I need and also to create a more generic *dndcontrol* so I can reuse this for other purposes (support for images, better control on fired events, etc ...)

**Problem**

At some point I would need to know if the source component that initiated the drag operation is the same as the target component that will receive the drop operation. For instance, *but not just staying focused on this particular case*, I'm ok for my listbox to receive text-transfer from itself (for item reordering or so) but not from other components (e.g. dragging text from some other component or window).

Reading for methods and properties from [DropTargetDragEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DropTargetDragEvent.htm) and [DropTargetDropEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DropTargetDropEvent.html) events I can receive from a [DropTarget](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DropTarget.html) listener it does not seem possible to know this. The only thing I could find was [isLocalTransfer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DropTargetDropEvent.html#isLocalTransfer()) but this only indicates if source and target are in the same JVM (and is only available at drop time, not during drag over for instance).

**Question**

I guess I can manage for a hack for the particular case of my custom Listbox, anyway is there a more standard/generic way **with Java** to know if source and target are the same in a drag and drop operation ?

NB1: Maybe I was thinking of attaching some sort of *drag listener* as I was able to attach a drop listener (i.e. `DropTarget`), but I don't know if this exist.

NB2: Sorry, I'm really new to Java programming and dnd handling. I hope explanations I gave will help to understand what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding callbacks on `MousePressed` and `MouseReleased` events in addition to the `DropTarget` listener will do. If drag events are received in between it is most certainly that the control is both the source and the target. Should have tilted myself about that earlier.